# How to store in a var a div content if this div exists (content is a number)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

it might be a simple question but I always have a NaN result.
`prodEl` is a div fetched by ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/ajax-products.html',
    success: function(response) {

        var prodEl = parseInt($(response).find("#id" + productId));

            if($(prodEl).find(".pricePerWeekEndSpecified").length>0){
                var resultWeekendPrice = parseFloat($(".pricePerWeekEndSpecified").text()).toFixed(2);
            }
            else{
                var resultWeekendPrice = ajaxDayPrice * 2;  
            }
          console.log(resultWeekendPrice)
    }
});
```

`resultWeekendPrice = NaN`
I also tried `.html()` or to wrap it with a `parseInt()`

Comment: include all relevant code to the OP

Comment: See creating a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe, parse `ajaxDayPrice` or check the data type of it?

Comment: you are always going to else so just do `parseInt(ajaxDayPrice)` also  your condition you can have `$(prodEl).find(".pricePerWeekEndSpecified").length > 0`

Comment: Thanks a lot guradio! the parsenInt around the ajaxDayPrice was the solution !

Comment: @Maloke glad it works also check your condition just as suggestion